# How to have one class take instances from two other different classes?

Tags: javascript, oop

I need to create three classes: customers, products, and orders. I want my orders class to take in instances from customers and products (i.e, be able to have an order contain information about the customer and the products they are ordering). What is the best way to set this up in JavaScript? I was originally thinking of having my customer and products class extend my order class but am I able to have order extend both my customer and products class?

Comment: Inheritance doesn't sound like the solution here.  Having `Order` or `Customer` extend one another doesn't make sense, because an order is not a customer and a customer is not an order.  It sounds like the `Order` class should just have properties which hold the product(s) and customer(s) associated with the order.

Comment: so within the Order class I would just make instances of customer and products?

Comment: I imagine it would receive those instances on its constructor, or otherwise have settable properties for them.  Though depending on how the application works and how entities are created/persisted it's certainly possible that the class can internally create instances from relevant data.  But the point here is simply to favor composition over inheritance.

Comment: I wouldn't even do that. Just have a key within each separate object that links them up. You're basically describing a database where foreign keys link various tables together.

Comment: could you please provide an example? I apologize, I am very new to OOP